# In jQuery, how many braces are needed for .css?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

Does the jQuery method ***.css*** need `div.css({"color":"red"});` or just `div.css("color":red");`?

If there's a specific use for both of them, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: The `css()` method has a few overloaded definitions, it is very well explained on http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: When a question shows little previous research usually gets downvoted a lot. Using google and reading relevant basic documentation before asking is the minimum of effort expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need this format:

```
div.css('color','red');
```

if there is only one setting.

However, to perform multiple settings in one instruction, you must use an object:

```
div.css({'color':'red','background':'yellow'});
```

or, if you prefer this format:

```
div.css({
    'color':'red',
    'background':'yellow'
});
```

Note:

In the first example, a `comma` separates the css selector from its setting. In an object, a `comma` separates each pair, and a `colon` separates the selector from its setting.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using JavaScript, it is either Parameters (x2) or an Object:

```
div.css("color", "red");
// Here color is one parameter,
// and red is the second parameter.
```

While this is an Object notation:

```
div.css({
  "color": "red"
});
```

The first option is better if you have only one parameter to set, i.e., `color`. If you have more than one, you can use the object notation:

```
div.css({
    'color':       'red',
    'background':  'yellow'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is used to **set Single css property**:

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

This is used to **Set Multiple CSS properties**:

```
$("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
```

Comment: Code is Code. Quote is Quote.